# Windows Server 2012 R2 Automatic Login

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, chef

I'm trying to setup automatic login on a Windows Server with a chef script however all the answers I have found thus far don't seem to be working for Windows Server 2012 R2.

I followed the registry edits in this Superuser question:
https://superuser.com/questions/499724/auto-login-windows-server-2012
but that doesn't seem to work on R2.

Somewhere else, I found that maybe a domain is needed for the login, so I added the DefaultDomainName key. That also did not work.

The only thing that seems to work is the autologon app https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905 .

Has anyone successfully enabled Automatic Login on Windows Server 2012 R2? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If Sysinternals autologon works for you, why is not a possible solution?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf Sorry for a long delay in the reply... I don't want to add another dependency to the process. I'm currently using systeminternals from CLI and it works just fine, but I can't rely on it forever.